# Retrieve history on terminal (macOS)

Tags: macos, terminal

When I use the command `clear` I am able to scroll up and find previous events. Nevertheless, sometimes I prefer <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Command-K) because it doesn't pollutes my command history (up and down arrows). However, I am not able to scroll up anymore.

Is there any way I can review previous events at these cases?

Comment: [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command) is a similar question that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the history of commands made up to a point, just type `history` into the terminal.

According to the [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command) that Mud provided, someone can press <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Alt-L) to clear the screen without deleting the history from terminal (it is scrollable).

In the same [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command), there's a script someone can execute the clear command before running another command such `vim` or `screen`